# How to pass separate fields to template via render

Tags: python, django, rest, api, crud

Here is my get function. I'm sending whole serialized object to the template which is not letting me use fields separately in template

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_employee(request):
        emp = employee.objects.all()
        serializer = employeeSerializer(emp, many=True)
        return render(request,'employee/employee_details.html',{'json_obj': serializer.data})
```

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't really help anyone to help you. Can you try to give your post a title that summarises the problem and then write a question in the body?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using serializers at all, if you just want to display model objects in a template? Also, show that actual template.

Answer (score 0):

If the apiview decorator is from the Rest framework, then working with context variables should look different.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET'])
def hello_world(request):
    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

The code you wrote looks like the classic Django view. In this case, you do not need a decorator. More details here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/